# How to access environment files of other project?

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I have 2 angular projects. First project is Main. I have to load environment files from second project to Main.

I know, we can access assets/a.json to other project by HttpClient.get.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
this.http.get('Path to that file').pipe(
    tap(data => console.log(data))
);
```

Comment: Not able to retrieve like this. If the file is in json format and also it is there in assets, we can able to get.